# Is there a possibility to add button in UITabBar in IPad?

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uitabbar

I want to know if it is possible to add an `UIButton` in `UITabBar` on the iPad. If so, please let me know.

Comment: have you looked into uibarbuttonitem http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

this is fairly straight forward if you look at the docs suggested by @Kyle the Unruly.

Here's an example of adding a built in button and your own image:

```
UIBarButtonItem * viewSnapShotButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(snapShotButtonPressed:)];
UIBarButtonItem * fontButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Font.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action: @selector(fontSize:)];

// Add buttons to the tab bar
NSMutableArray *topCentreItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UITabBar *topCentreTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 75];
[topCentreItems addObject:viewSnapShotButton];
[topCentreItems addObject:fontButton];
topCentreTabBar.items = topCentreItems;
```